# How in Sails to access globals in assets?

Tags: sails.js, assets, global

I am using Sails JS and would like to access globals (sails.config.myGlobals) in my assets, currently in js files.

I would have hoped I there is a similar way like injecting in ejs files. But its not.

Any ideas? Do I have to do a Grunt task for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with Sails.

However, what you can do is setting the variable in a ejs view file to access its value in your js asset file.

```
// someView.ejs
<script>
    myGlobals = '<%= config.myGlobals %>';
</script>
```

Comment: This answer is most right, because it includes that what I want is not possible in a direct way. I finally used "grunt-copy-part-of-file" to copy the lines into the js file in the asset folder.

Answer (score 3):

In your `config` folder create a config file for example `MyConfig.js` (name doesn't matter). Fill that config with something that you wanted like.

```
module.exports.myconfig = {
  configA: 'this is config A'
}
```

Use that config in your controller, like.

```
showconfig: function(req, res){
  res.view('viewname', {
    config: sails.config.myconfig
  });
}
```

Now in your EJS file that is called, by that example is `viewName.ejs` at `views` folder, you can use it like `<% config.configA %>`, and `this is config A` would be printed. Also if you want Front End js (in assets folder) able to read that value, just print it in `script` tag, like this.

```
<script>
  global.configA = '<%= config.configA %>';
</script>
```

Or if you use front end framework library, it can be placed under some `value`, `service`, or `factory`, not making global variable dirty, so other JS are able to read that value.

Comment: Thanks, but config.MyConfig.js to view was clear. I need access to the globals from assets (a file in the JS folder). I want some values in a JS file in the assets/js folder to be synced with some globals in the config folder.